# Is there a cross-platform way to get network statistics in C++?

Tags: c++, networking, cross-platform

Im interested in system-wide network load information per interface.

Target platforms are linux and windows.

UPD
Right answer is libpcap.

Comment: SNMP is the means to access the data, various implementations on Windows and Linux are available to provide it.  A choice of SNMP APIs is available to program to, SNMP++ might be convenient in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start for example using [zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/). Another type of tools is related to [Bandwidth Monitoring Tools For Linux](http://www.dynacont.net/documentation/linux/network_monitoring/). Also, take a look on [Monitoring Tools Web Based](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2012/03/22/linux-monitoring-tools/), and [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/download_cacti.php) seems to be a good solution.

Comment: This solutions are linux only. But tcpstat based on libpcap, that has windows port. So, its may help. Thanks.

Comment: These are tools not C++ APIs, more of an answer for superuser.com or serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Qt the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475266/verfiying-the-network-connection-using-qt-4-4).  It looks like you *don't* need the GUI part of the library.  [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) is totally cross platform and very well [supported](http://qt.digia.com/) and documented.

Another possibility is [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) if you can use boost.

The boost and [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) are mentioned in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library).

You might want to look at old SO questions in future.