# How to get the system network status in Qt?

Tags: qt, network-programming

How to get the system network status in Qt like we get event hits in .NET so that each and every time when we connect network get a signal of a status of the network connection?

Is there any function that have same functionality as I mentioned above?

Using ping and other methods of network configuration takes a small amount of time.
But I need to display it as fast as I could other than using a specific port to listen to the socket and display its error.

Can any one help me out of it?

Comment: You can see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475266/verfiying-the-network-connection-using-qt-4-4

Comment: I have already tried this method.But it's not a right answer as it fails with wifi.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good example of getting network information using QT:
http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Get_Network_information_using_Qt

For instance, you can get the signal strength from the public member, networkSignalStrength, of QSystemNetworkInfo. And, if you take a look at [QSystemNetworkInfo](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility-1.2/qsystemnetworkinfo.html) class reference, you can find signals such as networkSignalStrengthChanged so that you can handle something when network signal strength gets changed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: QSystemNetworkInfo class is part of the QtMobility APIs, which is unfortunately unavailable for desktop targets.So I cannot use this method for the desktop applications

Comment: QtMobility can be compiled for desktop separately, but as I see in Qt 5 it doesn't exist at all, some parts of it were moved to the Qt libs, but QSystemNetworkInfo class missed in Qt 5. @SLee The answer is not useful at all.